# Reader if and else statement

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am practicing programming in visual basic
I have 2 forms in visual basic.
The first form has a command button that will show the input data from the 2nd form
The second form has a textbox where I need to input a data and save it.

The data that I input in the 2nd form stores it in MySQL

the 1st form has a command button named "Show my Grade" and if I click that I want to display the Form 2 and show me the grade. It does work however if I didn't input any grade and then I click the "show my grade" button it crashes I don't know the error. I tried using the code "if READER.HasRows Then: 
but still it won't work 
also tried if READER.Read then:
else MessageBox.Show("there is no grade input at the moment")
Please help.

This is my current code in the command button in form 1.

```
Me.Visible = False
Form2.Show()


    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=qwerty;database=ssg"
        Dim COMMAND As New MySqlCommand
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        MySqlConn.Open()
        COMMAND.Connection = MySqlConn
        COMMAND.CommandText = "select grade from gradetable"
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        Form2.TextBox1.Text = READER("grade")                             
        End Sub
```

It works as long as I input a grade first, however if I didn't input any grade it crashes.

If I click the "Show my grade" button in form 1 without inputting a grade in form 2 I would like to just display a message saying "You still have no grade at the moment"

Please help.

Comment: What is the actual logic by which you want to select a `grade` from the table?  As of right now, you are selecting `grade` from all rows.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: As well as the issue mentioned above, if you've done any research on data readers then you know that you have to call their `Read` method in order to access any data. The first time you call `Read`, the first record in the result set is retrieved and you can then access its data. `Read` will return `True` each time it successfully reads a row, so it returns `False` when there are no more records to read.

Comment: I just want to display a message if there are no data to read. I tried   if reader.read() Then it will show the grade display else MessageBox.Show("There is no grade input at the moment")   end if

Answer (score 0):

1. The Using statement with a matching End Using. This is in place of Dim. It ensures that your objects are properly closed and disposed of even if there is an error. This is especially important for connections which should be closed as soon as possible.
2. I used the constructor of the connection to pass in the connection string. Setting the property is fine. This just saves a line of code.
3. Same idea with the command constructor. It can take the command text and the connection. Saves a little typing.
4. You had the right idea; using `.HasRows`. You just needed to add the `READER.Read` to get to the first record as explained in comments by jmcilhinney.

```vb
Private Sub GetGrade()
    Using MySqlConn As New 
        MySqlConnection("server=localhost; userid=root; password=qwerty; database=ssg")
        Using COMMAND As New MySqlCommand("select grade from gradetable", MySqlConn)
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Using READER As MySqlDataReader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
                If READER.HasRows Then
                    READER.Read()
                    Form2.TextBox1.Text = READER("grade")
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, no grade yet.")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ahmend Abdelhameed Thank you. I am blaming the May Windows 10 update. That is when the format problems began.